# How to access SnapshotStateList size in Kotlin Compose?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-desktop

How am I able to use the SnapshotStateList.size properly without causing an infinite loop of (I assume) recompositions? Based on other questions/answers it is most likely due to reading the list value and that read operation causes a recomposition... There doesn't seem to be anything about how to then find and use those read-only values, either directly or by other means.

Basically I am trying to use an if-else statement to make a composable visible, as long as there are already items within the list.

Below is heavily simplified

```
val list = remember {
  mutableStateListOf<String>()
}

/* update list */

if (list.size != 0) {
  /* add composables */
}
```

Whether I use `.size` or `.isEmpty()` I still get an infinite loop occurring.

I assume that I must convert this list into some other sort of list, but I haven't been successful in getting that to work either. `toList()` or `toMutableList()` haven't worked properly either. My intent was to work around the read operation in order to get the correct size value.

Thank you for any help/support that you can provide.

Comment: the problem is not reading, but `/* update list */`. e.g. wrap it in `LaunchedEffect`. Check out more in [doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects)

Comment: thank you. this seems to work now. i was able to wrap the launchedEffect over my getter functions and it allowed the rest of the function to work as expected.